# SWITCH with clauses differing by a constant increment

Tags: for-loop, powerbi, switch-statement, dax

Below is my `SWITCH`. I want to put it in a loop. I want to constantly increase my `SWITCH` by 2.5, because I have a lot of different values from 0 to 1000.

```
Order Amount =
SWITCH (
TRUE(),
Order[Amount Order] >= 0 && Order[Amount Order] < 5 , "< 5",
Order[Amount Order] >= 5.1 && Order[Amount Order] <= 7.5, "5 - 7.5",
Order[Amount Order] >= 7.51 && Order[Amount Order] <= 10, "7.51 - 10",
Order[Amount Order] >= 10.01 && Order[Amount Order] <= 12.5, "10.01 - 12.5",
Order[Amount Order] >= 12.51 && Order[Amount Order] <= 15, "12.51 - 15",Blank())
```

Comment: What do you mean to put this in a loop? If you need to add more group in your switch, then just use excel formula to make it easier. ="Order[Amount Order] >= " & A1 & " && Order[Amount Order] <= "&  B1 & ", """ & A1 & "-" & B1 &""", "

Where A1 = lower band, A2 upper band

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [This](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/For-and-While-Loops-in-DAX/ba-p/636314) can help you, just let me know if it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This formula succeeded for me:

```
Order Amount = 
VAR _ceil = CEILING('Order'[Amount Order] / 2.5, 1) * 2.5
VAR _big_result = CONVERT(_ceil-2.49, STRING) & " - " & CONVERT(_ceil, STRING)
RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(),
    'Order'[Amount Order] >= 0 && 'Order'[Amount Order] < 5 , "< 5",
    'Order'[Amount Order] >= 5 && 'Order'[Amount Order] <= 7.5, "5 - 7.5",
    _big_result)
```

[image]